# Stick an element to the iPhone keyboard (JS, CSS?)

Tags: css, mobile, keyboard, positioning, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a webapp using jQuery Mobile. One thing I want to do is to display some auto-complete suggestions for certain input fields. I want the block with those suggestions to appear as if it extends the onscreen keyboard, resting exactly on its top edge and staying there when I scroll the page.

A quick and dirty illustraion:

[image: auto-complete suggestions]

I see similar sort of things being done in some native apps. Is there a way to achieve this with just jQuery/JS and CSS?

Comment: There are difficulties with `position:fixed` in Safari for iOS: the only way I've seen it done is to absolutely position it, fade it out before the scroll starts, and then reposition it and fade it in when the scroll stops. Safari for iOS doesn't allow you to do anything whilst the scroll is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this will be possible.
The keyboard is a system entity that belongs to the browser.
You can manipulate the way it is displayed slightly... tailored for email, URL, numeric or phone number.

Have a read here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is only possible as a native app UNLESS you figure out a way (probably with JavaScript) to have your auto-complete suggestions "float" a certain height from the top of the viewing window.

For example, if you measure the screen in pixels, float your auto-complete "bar" x-number of pixels from the top of the iPhone's status bar. Tricky, but possible